# Looking for a specific word in a line of text on submit

Tags: php

So I have this code: if I type something with a specific word it will show up, for example, `if ($_POST['text']` it will look for the word smile and convert it to some other text `$out_smile`. This method works well but when it comes to adding text in between the text like `"I love to smile"` it won’t recognize `"smile"` it will recognize it as `"I love to smile"`. I intuitively know the reason for that. Is there any way to add a string?

```
if ($_POST['text'] == "Smile") { 
    $out_smile = 'My Code here <img src="URL">';
}
```

I want to do something like this. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
 if (Found in the entire $text if there is a word == "smile") { 
    $out_smile = 'My Code here <img src="URL">';
 }
```

OR

```
  $Auto_detect_left = "Extra text in the left hand"; //I Dont know how i am gonna do it
  $Auto_detect_right = "Extra text in the right hand"; //I Dont know how i am gonna do it
  $Out_result = ".$Auto_detect_left.$text.$Auto_detect_right;
 if ($_POST['text'] == "$Out_result") { 
    $out_smile = 'My Code here <img src="URL">';
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are asking to verify that a string is contained inside different string, what you want is probably `strpos`.

```
$haystack = 'arglebarglearglebargle smile!';
$needle = 'smile';
$pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);

if ($pos === false) {
    //$needle is not present in $haystack
} else {
    //$needle is in $haystack at position $pos
}
```

Please note the use of `===`, its use is mandatory in this case, or it will not always work properly. (Later on you should probably look up the difference between `==` and `===` in php.)